# Unexpected error 0x8ffe2740 occurred in IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have installed IIS in my system (WINDOWS-XP). While i am seeing IIS window,  the Default web site is in stop mode. when i am ready to start IIS. It shows "**Unexpected error 0x8ffe2740 occurred**"

Finally, I discovered that its caused by Skype. It listens to port 80 for incoming call. Now, most of the time IIS starts before Skype starts. So IIS works but if you restart IIS or try to start IIS after Skype is started then you will get this error message.

For this,
I changed my Skype settings

```
 Skype File-> Options -> Connection
 Uncheck Use Port 80 as an alternative for incoming connections.
```

But even though i am unable to start my IIS.

Please help me some one..

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After restart my system, my problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and I solve it using a firewall not allowing skype to do anything else more than open the ports to talk or chat.
Restart IIS after this or restart computer.

Additionally you can check for other programs like teamViewer, that also try to use port 80.
May be a little bit hard to check ports on windows xp, xampp has a program to check ports that is very handy for this kind of things.

I hope this can be useful to your problem.