# Unexpected stopping of IIS server

Tags: asp.net, webforms, iis-7

My project is a ASP.NET web form project. It has a MySQL database connection. My problem is as soon as i run the project, the IIS server stops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to turn off antivirus you are using and temporarily disable Windows firewall in turn. Sometimes simple system restart may help. Also try to see these posts:
[Unexpected error 0x8ffe2740 occurred in IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12545032/unexpected-error-0x8ffe2740-occurred-in-iis) 
http://www.ithacks.com/2010/04/21/unexpected-error-0x8ffe2740-when-starting-ftp-or-iis/ 
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/816944